# Sort LinkedList w.r.t. Enums By Preserving Insertion Order

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, linked-list

I follow [Java Collection How to - Sort List on object fields enum constant values](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Collection_How_to/List/Sort_List_on_object_fields_enum_constant_values.htm) tutorial and come up with following implementation

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

/*from   w  w w.j  av a2 s.  c  o  m*/
enum Level {
    HIGH, MEDIUM, LOW;
}

class Person {
    private Level severity;
    private String name;

    public Person(Level severity, String name) {
        super();
        this.severity = severity;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Level getSeverity() {
        return severity;
    }

    public void setSeverity(Level severity) {
        this.severity = severity;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person p8 = new Person(Level.LOW, "8");
        Person p9 = new Person(Level.HIGH, "9");
        Person p10 = new Person(Level.HIGH, "10");
        Person p11 = new Person(Level.LOW, "11");

        List<Person> persons = new LinkedList<Person>();
        persons.add(new Person(Level.HIGH, "1"));
        persons.add(new Person(Level.MEDIUM, "2"));
        persons.add(new Person(Level.LOW, "3"));
        persons.add(new Person(Level.HIGH, "4"));
        persons.add(new Person(Level.MEDIUM, "5"));
        persons.add(new Person(Level.LOW, "6"));
        persons.add(new Person(Level.LOW, "7"));

        sort(persons);

        for (Person person : persons) {
            System.out.println(person.getName() + " " + person.getSeverity());
        }

        System.out.println("\nAfter\n");

        persons.add(p8);
        persons.add(p9);
        persons.add(p10);
        persons.add(p11);

        sort(persons);

        for (Person person : persons) {
            System.out.println(person.getName() + " " + person.getSeverity());
        }
    }

    private static void sort(List<Person> persons) {
        Collections.sort(persons, new Comparator<Person>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Person person1, Person person2) {
                if (person1.getSeverity() == person2.getSeverity()) {
                    return person1.getName().compareTo(person2.getName());
                } else {
                    return person1.getSeverity().compareTo(person2.getSeverity());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
1 HIGH
4 HIGH
2 MEDIUM
5 MEDIUM
3 LOW
6 LOW
7 LOW

After

1 HIGH
10 HIGH
4 HIGH
9 HIGH
2 MEDIUM
5 MEDIUM
11 LOW
3 LOW
6 LOW
7 LOW
8 LOW
```

I want to preserve the insertion order in a sorted list irrespective of how many times a list is sorted and new objects are added. I thought by using `LinkedList` I can achieve the goal but failed.

**Required Output**

```
1 HIGH
4 HIGH
2 MEDIUM
5 MEDIUM
3 LOW
6 LOW
7 LOW

After

1 HIGH
4 HIGH
9 HIGH
10 HIGH
2 MEDIUM
5 MEDIUM
3 LOW
6 LOW
7 LOW
8 LOW
11 LOW
```

Is there a way to maintain the order of insertion too even after sortings/insertions ?

Comment: So which is it? You want to maintain insertion order, or you want to sort it?

Comment: The whole point of sorting is to change the order of the elements of the list. If you want to keep the insertion order, sorting doesn't make sense. If you want both, then you need two lists: one, unsorted, keeping the insertion order, and the other one, sorted, where elements are thus ordered according to your comparator rules.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I want to have a sorted list w.r.t. Enum, but also preserving the insertion order.

Comment: Your comment has been addressed by @JBNizet. Either use two lists, sort on the fly whenever you need, or create your own custom list implementation (which I would highly advise against).

Comment: Hmm, so I think in that case I have to use `HashMap<Level, List<Person>>`, if not achievable by list.

Comment: I still don't understand what you want. A Map won't sort your list. And you said you want the persons soted by level, but you sort them by level, then by name. Why? What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to keep the insertion order *among the persons with the same level*? If so, drop the name comparison from your comparator.

Comment: @JBNizet you pointed to the error that I made. I blindly copy paste code from the tutorial. I wrongly compare the name, now my `public int compare` method has only one statement i.e. `return person1.getSeverity().compareTo(person2.getSeverity());`. It also generating required output. Thanks

Comment: And all your comparator should be replaced by `Comparator.comparing(Person::getLevel)`.